# pyFFTW links more variables than expected

Tags: python, variable-assignment, pyfftw

I'm using python to write a split-step fourier transform method using pyfftw. I think I mostly understand what is going on, but I can't understand why so many of my variables change when I try to operate on just one.

In the code below, I start with a 1D array (complex128), `E`, and initially assign it to `a`. Then I go through planning the DFTs so that I have 2 operations that go back and forth to between time and frequency.

My code:

```
a = pyfftw.empty_aligned(npts, dtype='complex128')
b = pyfftw.empty_aligned(npts, dtype='complex128')

a[:] = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fftshift(E);

fft_object = pyfftw.FFTW(a, b)
EFT = fft_object()

ifft_object = pyfftw.FFTW(b, a, direction='FFTW_BACKWARD')
E = ifft_object()

A0 = E;
a[:] = np.power(np.absolute(A0),2)
IFT = fft_object()
b[:] = chi*IFT
Iz = np.power(np.absolute(A0),2) + ifft_object()
NLfn = A0 * Iz
```

The problem is once I get into the second part of the code, assigning `a[:] = np.power(np.absolute(A0),2)` seems to alter `A0` as well as `a`.

This also happens in `Iz = np.power(np.absolute(A0),2) + fft_object()`, where in each case variables that I have assigned `a` or `b` to seem to remain linked rather than being temporary variables.

What's going on???

Answer (score 0):

`E` is `a` (check by doing `E is a`). This is because the second argument to the `FFTW` object is the output array, which is what is returned when you do `ifft_object()`.

You then assign `A0` to be `E`, so absolutely when you change `a`, you also change `A0`, since they are the same object.

If you use the `FFTW` object, you need to be careful of such things. It's designed to minimise copies, so it's up to you to get the arrays correct. If you don't want to do this, I suggest using the `pyfftw.builders` interface.